# I can hop and sing

Tags: meaning

I can hop and sing.

What does sentence imply:

1. I can do two actions at the same time.
2. I can hop first and then sing.
3. I can do each action.

I probably guess that #3 is definitly ok, but what about 1 and 2? Which one does the sentence closely mean?

Comment: The doubled degree of conditionality in "probably guessing" clashes with the certainty of "definitely!" (Check your spelling there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 3 would be closest, but number 1 might be thought of, depending on the context. It would be very rare for this sentence to have number 2's meaning.

Comment: I agree; for the sentence in the question, Interpretation #2 seems unlikely. However, as you correctly point out, context can change things around.  For example, if I say, _"Let's do dinner and a movie,"_ there's a good chance I mean, "Let's go out to dinner, and then go see a movie."